# Generate dynamic css based on variables angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am working on a admin panel developed with angular 4 and trying to integrate a sections to customize styling like change color, bg etc.
I already have developed a sections to save settings in database got them on app load as json using API.

Now I am trying to generate a dynamic css using values from json, I tried with following code in main component but its not working

```
@Component({
      templateUrl: 'card.html',
      styles: [`
        .card {
          height: 70px;
          width: 100px;
          color: {{css.cardColor}};
        }
      `],
})
```

I am not sure how I should load the css values in component and use them in style tag. I didnt find any other solution for same.

Another way is to use angular animation concept but the css is going to be huge and its not possible to implements it whole with angular animation using triggers and all. I believe there is a solution for this as it seems a genuine requirements and should have done by lots of other developers.

Any help is appreciable.

Edit : can not use ngStyle as its going to be applied on almost all elements as its for whole application and not only for specific element.

Comment: I think this would make an excellent feature request.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Direct approach available in angular is using ngstyle as follows

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'color': style.colorVal ? style.colorVal : '#000', 'font-size' : style.fontSize ? style.fontSize : '16px' }"></div>
```

After going through different methods and approached to add dynamic css to all pages on angular app I ended up with following solutions.

Requirement : generate dynamic css based on values returned from and API to change design and styling.

Solution :

1. create a new component and create a service to load dynamic css variables from API.
2. Add style tag in template file and use variable values for properties.
3. Load this template on all pages or on main template.
4. On app build style will be moved to head tag.

Code sample

```
import { CssService} from './Css.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'DynamicCss',
  templateUrl: './DynamicCss.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./DynamicCss.component.scss']
})
export class ServiceProviderComponent implements OnInit {
    cssVariables: any;
    constructor(private cssService:CssService){
        /* call the service/api to get the css variable values in cssVariables */

    }
}
```

Now apply css using jquery or javascript to append css with help of function like following

```
appendCss(customData)
{
     let text = '.custom-form-1 {
            background-image: url("`+customData.background_image+`");
         }';
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("style").append(text);
      });
}
```

and call this function after loading custom data from service or other variable like I did it `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.appendCss(this.customizeFormData);
}
```

Its using jquery but can be done with javascript/typescript as well if you dont want to use jquery in your angular app

Other useful resource  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9343#issuecomment-312035896

Comment: you should post the code solution here. can you please show how you use the variable values inside css style properties ?

Comment: can you post some code example of this solution? This looks to be a really good solution.

Comment: I just tried this with Angular 4 and Angular CLI ~1.6.0 and didn't work, but this worked: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9343#issuecomment-312035896

Comment: this answer is incomplete.

Comment: @NinjaCoding And in what terms its incomplete ?

Comment: Answer is incomplete because of the lack of code refering to the most important of your answer, which is de css service

Comment: @VikramSingh Please remove the first half of this answer.  According to this bug (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13802) and its linked duplicate, this feature is not implemented.  
I've tested {{interpolation}} in the <style> tag, and it does not work.

Comment: @VikramSingh thanks!  To be sure, I really wanted {{interpolation}} in the <style> tag to work.  I'm disappointed that the Angular team has not implemented this.

Comment: You should mark someone else's response as the answer since there was someone who suggested you use ngStyle

Comment: Is there nowadays a way how to create really dynamic css based on component variable? I need to override bootstrap variable (something like `$primary: {{myColor}}`), which is, as far as I know, not possible to achieve this way.

Answer (score 53):

You can use `ngStyle` to dynamically add the `css` to your page from json.

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'color': variable ? 'red' : 'blue'}"></div>
```

An another example:

```
 <div md-card-avatar [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + post.avatar + ')', 'background-size': 'cover'  }"></div>
```

here I have loaded background image from json-data.

Comment: Thats a good suggestion Ajinkya but as I mentioned its going to be a huge css and will be applied to almost every element. so can not use ngStyle

Comment: @Vikram, an issue has been already filed for this [https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7108](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7108)

there are some suggestion as well, this might be helpful to you

Answer (score 16):

You can bind only `style.color`:

```
<div class="card" [style.color]="cardColor">lorem ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

[`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) is used to set the dynamic class basis of your variable value as below

Ts File Component:

```
@Component ({
    selector:'simple-comp',
    template:`   <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li *ngClass="{'active': step==='step1'}" (click)="step='step1; '">Step1</li>
        <li *ngClass="{'active': step==='step2'}"  (click)="step='step2'">Step2</li>
        <li *ngClass="{'active': step==='step3'}" (click)="step='step3'">Step3</li>
       </ol>`
})

export class SimpleComponent {
    public step: string = 'step1'; // change value like step1, step2, step3
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">
 ...
</some-element>
```

Answer (score 2):

For background use, the JSON method is used for color:

```
<ion-list-header class="background-size"
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + data.headerImage + ')'}"
*ngIf="data.headerImage != null">
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: Can you or someone else explain: "The JSON method is used for color"

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to dynamically style an element nested within a component, (specifically http://tb.github.io/ng2-nouislider/), so similar to the OP, ngStyle was not suitable.

My approach was to use a reference variable in my template (https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) to access the native element of the component and find the target child node using querySelector (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

The required style was then applied with Renderer 2. Example below and on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r3bs1d.

```
import { Component, Renderer2, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
    backgroundColour = '#ff0000';
    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }
    @ViewChild('parent', { static: false }) parent;
    ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.parent.nativeElement.querySelector('.child'), 'background', this.backgroundColour);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div #parent>
    <div class="child">Child Element</div>
</div>
```

For minor styling changes at least, I think this is a feasible solution.