# Use variable in style tag in angular template?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular5

I am working on angular 5 application, and I have requirement of applying dynamic css in style tag in template.
I have tried some solutions but they are not working.

app.component.ts

```
customCss : any;

constructor(){}

ngOnInit(){
   this.customCss['color'] = "red";
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div>
   <span class="custom_css">This is angular 5 application</span>
</div>

<style>
   .custom_css{
      color: {{customCss.color}};
   }
</style>
```

When I inspect the custom_css class in browser then in style it shows

```
.custom_css{
   color: {{customCss.color}};
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46536494/112104

Comment: Its working on all other cases but doesn't work for css part.

Comment: I don't this Angular will allow you to have `style` in template. But it's easy to create dynamic element.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `[ngStyle]` directive:

```
<span [ngStyle]="{'color': 'red'}">
 This is angular 5 application
</span>
```

Or like so:

```
<span [ngStyle]="applyStyles()">
 This is angular 5 application
</span>
```

And in component:

```
applyStyles() {
    const styles = {'color' : 'red'};
    return styles;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

By the way if you set the color like this:

```html
<div [style.color]="color"></div>
```

where `color='var(--cssValue)'` it **would not work!**

However, this works correctly:

```html
<div [ngStyle]="{color: color}"></div>
```

Comment: You can however use var() like this `<div [style.color]="'var(--poop)'">poop</div>` where you've defined `:host { --poop: brown; }`. You wouldn't want to typically do this but that's how you could.

Answer (score 8):

The given answer works if you have few elements to change in a given component, if you need to change the full overall look and feel of your app based on user's choice (and on the fly), the only way i found so far is to override css in the javascript like the following:

```
this.stylesService.get().subscribe(({ customStyles }) => {
     const style = document.createElement('style');
     style.innerHTML = 
     `.picture {
         background-image: url(${customStyles.backgroundUrl});
     }
     h1, h2 {
         color: ${customStyles.primaryColor};
     }`;

     document.body.appendChild(style);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [style.customClass]=“methodInComponent()”...

This will apply the class if the method in your component returns true.