# How to put a style on a angular variable

Tags: ionic-framework

Hello i want to put a style opacity:0.3 on img

```
  <ion-content [style]="getBackgroundImg()">  

  getBackgroundImg() {
        const img = this.mediaDetails.image_path;
        const style = `background-image: url(${img}); `;
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
 }
```

Note: i want put opacity only on const img not on the whole ion-content. It doesnt take the opacity in the object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use variable in style tag in angular template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449750/use-variable-in-style-tag-in-angular-template)

Comment: mediaDetails: any = {};            this.mediaDetails.image_path['opacity'] = "0.4"; and i am getting 'Cannot create property opacity on string'

Comment: you want to add opacity to an image in ion-content ? or to background?

Comment: on background, not ion-content because i have content there buttons, data etc

Answer (score 0):

You can add the opacity property in a style e.g.

```
const style = `background-image: url(${img}); opacity:0.3 `;
```

Comment: i did that. It changes not only the image but the whole ion-content.