# how to change dynamically the color of Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I change dynamically my theme in My project, And I want to change the color(or background) of the Angular Material component : checkbox, radio button, slide toggle, textarea...

How to change them

example :

```html
 <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="expression" [color]="colorCss"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

ColorCss is the variable from the component

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tomastrajan/0007da8cd177143efc9659bf5ac99354 this might help

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46047502/9766215)?

Comment: @Rajoan, did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

While using material components, Color attribute is only accepts three colors i.e. primary, warn and accent which are default in your theme.

If you are changing theme it means your primary, warn and accent colors are get changed.

If your material component is having one from these color then it get automatically changed.
But if your material component having custom colors than you have to change that with the help of ngStyle or ngClass directives.