# How to import css with variable in components - SASS

Tags: css, angular, variables, sass, path

I have to import one CSS in my Angular component and I am creating a variable for path to import the CSS in component.

I am creating path variable with Sass:

```
$fpath: 'assets/scss/helpers' !default;
```

And I am calling this path in component.css:

```
@import 'assets/scss/helpers/variables'; //this is working and have $fpath variable
@import '#{$fpath}/icons';
```

But its giving me an error:

```
@import #{$fpath}/icons;
           ^
      Undefined variable: "$fpath".
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried to use it as `@import #{$fpath}'/icons';`?

Comment: Might checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047502/generate-dynamic-css-based-on-variables-angular