# Inline CSS with angular interpolation

Tags: css, angular, inline, background-color, string-interpolation

I am working on Angular and is trying to set this div background color dynamically based on the color specified by `"cardData.color"`.

E.g.

```
cardData = {id: '1', color: '#202020'};
```

I've tried the code shown below but it doesn't work.

```
<div style="background-color: {{cardData.color}}; padding: 10px 20px;"></div>
```

Is there any way, I can set the background color dynamically based on the object's color?? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate dynamic css based on variables angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047502/generate-dynamic-css-based-on-variables-angular)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `[]` to get the value of `cardData.color` without `{{}}` also you can  use `style.backgroundColor`.

```
<div [style.backgroundColor]="cardData.color" style="padding: 10px 20px;"></div>
```

Another way to do it:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': cardData.color , 'padding': '10px 20px' }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<div [style.background-color]="cardData.color" style="padding: 10px 20px;"></div>
```

Comment: `backgroundColor` no `background-color`!!

Answer (score 0):

Following angular style guide I would recommend to use [[ngStyle]](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle):

```
<div  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': cardData.color}">...</div >
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[ngStyle]` to have access to variables from the component.

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': cardData.color, 'padding': '10px 20px'}">Some Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both **ngStyle** and **style** bindings

For:
**Style Binging**

```
<div [style.backgroundColor] = "cardData.color"></div>
```

And For:
**ngStyle Binding**

```
 <div [ngStyle] = "{ backgroundColor: cardData.color}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

below code snippet has worked for me

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color':cardData.color}"></div>
```