# to use .component.ts property in css file correctlt in angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-components

I have  a components folder "story-section" with those files

[image]

I want to use mobImg and deskImg properties in CSS as a background image.

The problem is in CSS file lines 2 and 12.
story-section.componnet.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-story-section',
  templateUrl: './story-section.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./story-section.component.css']
})
export class StorySectionComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input() public mobImg = "";
  @Input() public deskImg = "";
  @Input() public storyHeader = "";
  @Input() public by = "";
  @Input() public time = "";

  constructor(){}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }
}
```

story-section.component.css

```
.bgImg {
  background-image: $mobImg;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .bgImg {
    background-image: var($deskImg);
  }
}
```

story-section.component.html

```
<div class="bgImg h-[400px] md:h-[600px] text-white flex flex-col justify-end text-[13px] group hover:-translate-y-5">
  <div class="px-10">{{ time }}</div>
  <div class="my-1 text-[18px] font-bold leading-[25px] px-10">
    {{ storyHeader }}
  </div>
  <div class="px-10">{{ by }}</div>
  <hr class="my-4 opacity-60 px-10" />
  <div class="mb-10 mt-1 px-10">
    <app-arrow-button arrowButtonText="READ STORY"></app-arrow-button>
  </div>
  <div
    class="bg-gradient-to-tr from-clrFrom via-clrVia to-clrTo h-[6px] w-full hidden group-hover:block"
  ></div>
</div>
```

github: https://github.com/Izabelaognadze/photosnap-multi-page-website

Comment: It is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56983431/inline-css-with-angular-interpolation). I made a [Working example](https://stackblitz-starters-5kd24c.stackblitz.io) for you.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but the second link is not opening, and the first link I didn't find helpful. If it's possible to create a meet, I could show you the problem, and maybe you could fix it.

Comment: Sorry, SO is not a coding service. If the stackblitz is not loading it doesn't matter. You can just have a look at the code in the TS file.