# Dynamically change row color in ngx-datatable

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am using ngx-datatable with Angular 7. I need to update the table row color dynamically according to the color value which is comes with the data set.

I have tried `rowClass` feature. But it is not the what I am looking for.

How can I set the row `background-color` dynamically with color code in data set?

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatable-row-color-tzzfb9)

Answer (score 6):

You were really close in your StackBlitz. All the rows were green because you were not deciding anything based on your row data. You were always returning `true` (which means it always uses the same class). If you return one or more class names based on a condition, you would get the desired result.

**Classes**

```
/deep/ .row-color1 {
    background-color: rgb(96, 212, 96);
}
/deep/ .row-color2 {
    background-color: rgb(51, 201, 228);
}
```

**getRowClass() Typescript function**

```
  getRowClass = (row) => {    
   return {
     'row-color1': row.gender == "Male",
     'row-color2': row.gender == "Female",
   };
  }
```

Here i am returning two classes based on two conditions. The ngx-datable [API documentation](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/api/table/inputs#rowclass) says that you can return either an object or a string (the above example being an object returned).

I have created a new [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatable-row-color-pxkwpx) with the fix (forked on yours)

Answer (score 0):

I would not particularly focus on ngx-datatable package, but look into more general solutions, like here:

[Generate dynamic css based on variables angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047502/generate-dynamic-css-based-on-variables-angular)

So I would go with dynamic classes and then enhance the css with the needed colors.