# What are the ways to add conditional css file in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular

How can we apply css files or import css files conditionally in angular.

Note: We should have multiple css files and on condition it should apply the css file to the angular component.

In how many ways can we achieve it? any approach could be usable.

Comment: What type of conditions? (Typically you would conditionally apply CSS styling based on a class that you set conditionally.)

Comment: The Condition is on getting URL Params value we should apply the correct css file like url params value is red then red.css file should be imported or used.

Comment: Got it. This might be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58553876/angular-2-how-to-dynamically-change-an-entire-css-stylesheet-based-on-url-quer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 - How to dynamically change an entire CSS stylesheet based on URL queryparams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58553876/angular-2-how-to-dynamically-change-an-entire-css-stylesheet-based-on-url-quer)

Comment: No it doesn't satisfy my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ngClass directive:

```
<div id="mydiv" [ngClass]="{'myCSSclass' : condition}"></div>
```

Comment: enjoy @EswarSaiPallapolu

Comment: @EswarSaiPallapolu the answer was not enough for you?