# Angular: Show difference between Two Class Components

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular8

I have a Parent component. It injects data into two @Input() Child duplicate card components, showing html. In addition, there is difference class in parent, flagging difference between the two classes .

When displaying class members in html below, is there method to highlight items which have changed in,  Without Modifying Child Components? Prefer not to inject difference logic in child card components. Would rather have the parent controller highlight differences, without overall logic leaking into child components.

All child components have same css class referring to member name, .city refers to city, .zipcode pertains to item zipcode,

Might need to create javascript function, and then applying in Angular in ngOnit, still researching, trying to apply this answer maybe? [Generate dynamic css based on variables angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047502/generate-dynamic-css-based-on-variables-angular)

[image]

```
export class PropertyLocation {   
    streetName: string;
    streetType: string;
    postdirectional?: string;
    unitNumber?: string;
    unitType?: string;
    city: string;
    state?: string;
    zipcode: number;

    effectiveStartDate: Date;
    addressChangeReason?: AddressChangeReasonDto;
    addressSource?: SourceOfAddressDto;
}
```

Difference class: feel free to restructure class in parent, to make solution easier if required

```
export class DifferenceClass {   
    ClassMember: string;
    DifferentFlag: boolean;
}
```

derived from

```
function isSame(obj1:any, obj2:any): DifferenceClass {
   let difference: DifferenceClass[];
   for (const key in obj1) {
     if (obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
       differences.push(new DifferenceClass(key,true));
     }
     else 
       differences.push(new DifferenceClass(key,false));
   }
   return differences;
 }
```

Comment: know what you are saying, would ngclass have to be injected at the child element? trying to look for solution in parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom Directive is helpful to separate some UI logic from the Component class.

Example:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[highlighter]',
})

@Input('streetName') streetName: string;

export class HighlighterDirective {
  constructor(private host: ElementRef,
              private rd: Renderer2) {}
} 

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes['streetName'].currentValue != changes['streetName'].previousValue) {
    this.rd.setStyle(this.host.nativeElement, 'color', 'red')
  }
}
```

p.s. code is completely from my memory, could be some types, syntax errors. But you get the idea - Directive has access to the same inputs defined on the component:

`<custom-component [streetName] highlighter></custom-component>`

Then you can use `ngOnChanges` or other technique to distinguish when the property has changed its value and use Renderer2 (for the best practices), to apply direct changes to the DOM.